# i wanna run a bot on discord with my database

Tags: python, database, discord

I have been tried run this bot https://github.com/mrtolkien/inhouse_bot in my data base, I managed to run it on the docker of the creator of the code, but in my database I couldn't run the bot, because i'm so noob.

On `cogs.database_orm.mini_migration_toll.py line 11` i have been tried put psql and mongo, but when i run the bot on vscode appears `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins`

i don't know how self run the bot, basically, i wanna run the bot with my edits on the commands of the bot.

Comment: First learn about the stack, making a bot is not an easy thing.

Comment: yeah, i know i tried so much things to make this bot run with python, but I always get this result.